# Builder Pattern and Json alias name

Tags: java, json, builder

I want to construct the builder object for the below class

```
@Value
@Builder
public static class Input {
    String name;
    Source source;
}

@Value
@Builder
public static class Source {
    //@JsonAlias({"metric", state"})
    //@JsonProperty("state")
    Metric metric ;
}

@Value
@Builder
public static class Metric {
    String ref;
}
```

I want to construct the objects like

```
Input.builder()
        .name("state")
        .source(Source.builder()
            .metric(Metric.builder()
                .ref("ref")
                .build())
            .build())
        .build()
```

At the same time , the 'metric' name will be changed like 'state' in one of the scenarios,

```
Input.builder()
        .name("state")
        .source(Source.builder()
            .state(Metric.builder()
                .ref("ref")
                .build())
            .build())
        .build()
```

Constructing the objects differ only in the name of metric / state. The structure remains same. I tried with @JsonAlias and not finding it helpful. Can anyone give me the correct reference or how to use the different name in builder pattern when the structure is same?

Comment: Even if you could give the field two names somehow, how do you expect your JSON serializer to know which one you mean for a specific instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to tell lombok what is the name of the field you want in a constructor and annotate with @Builder. see the following code and static class Metric

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

public class Test {

@Value
@Builder
public static class Input {
    String name;
    Source source;
}

@Value
public static class Source {
    Metric metric ;
    
    @Builder
    public Source(Metric state, Metric metric) {
        this.metric = state != null ? state : metric;
    }
}

@Value
@Builder
public static class Metric {
    String ref;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Input.builder()
            .name("state")
            .source(Source.builder()
                    .state(Metric.builder()
                            .ref("ref")
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .build();
       
       Input.builder()
            .name("state")
            .source(Source.builder()
                    .metric(Metric.builder()
                            .ref("ref")
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. But , I want construct the objects with the name state & measurement.  Input.builder()
        .name("state")
        .source(Source.builder()
            .metric(Metric.builder()
                .ref("ref")
                .build())
            .build())
        .build() In other scenarios ,  Input.builder()
            .name("state")
            .source(Source.builder()
                    .state(Metric.builder()
                            .ref("ref")
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .build();

Comment: in the constructor of Source with the annotation, add another Metric parameter "source" and in the code check if one of the parameters is null use the other. and then you can do exactly what you want.

Comment: i updated the answer. but i really think what you want is bad practice and is really confusing and there is no technical reason why this would be necessary. you should avoid doing these kinds of things in the future.

Comment: Yes Tom. I accept that this is not good practice but the actual business requirement is we have to construct the object with different names. If we have the same structure and only the name changes in the JSON construction , we can use this approach. Apart from this approach , I do not get the better way to implement this . Any suggestion from your side?